# Call ajax using jQuery after enabling url mapping in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ws.aspx/RetC',
    ...
```

In my ASP.NET application, I enabled url mapping by adding :

```
<urlMappings>
  <add mappedUrl="~/mem/ws.aspx" url="~/w" />
...
</urlMappings>
```

The ajax call now returns 'Not Found' error. I tried different options for the url such as /w/RetC or w/Retc, but none worked. Does anybody have any idea what the problem is?